# Attribute contains only ID, not whole entity, in persisted TypeORM entity

Tags: node.js, typescript, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I've got this entity class:

```
@Entity("organization")
export class OrganizationEntity {

    // ...

    @PrimaryColumn({name: "party_id"})
    @OneToOne(() => PartyEntity, {cascade: true})
    @JoinColumn({name: "party_id", referencedColumnName: "id"})
    party: PartyEntity

}
```

Then I create a new `OrganizationEntity` and persist it:

```
const savedOrganizationEntity = await this.organizationTypeOrmRepository.save(organizationEntity);
// see Repository.save
```

However, the returned `savedOrganizationEntity` contains a string in the field party, not a `PartyEntity` object.

How can I fix this behaviour, so that `OrganizationEntity.party` contains a `PartyEntity`, not a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is working as designed: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3490